# fixed drop list on new page

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am working on webpage which searches data from database.

To filter search user inputs text and select items from drop list.

I code it in Javascript. I would like to learn how to make these items fixed after new page loaded.

For example, I have selected 'BMW' from 'Cars' drop list. When BMW cars appear on new page, drop list should stay same with 'BMW' text.

It should be the same with text area(blank). On next page it should stay same

Thanks for interest

Comment: which is your programming language

Comment: Give us some code samples if possible. I'm having a hard time understanding what your asking for.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?
"On the fly" filtering? And just show the data that is matching the string?
If you have a sample of your html/javascript we can help you.